# Flutter Drawer when menu icon is tapped

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am currently trying out drawer widget. I have constructed an appbar with a hamburger menu icon, title text and a search icon.
Here is my code:
`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hexcolor/hexcolor.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: PreferredSize(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, top: 10, bottom: 10),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(Icons.menu),
                      Text(
                        'Appbar',
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Icon(Icons.search)
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(40)),
            backgroundColor: Hexcolor('#e9f1fe'),
            body: Center(
              child: Text('Experimenting drawer'),
            )));
  }
}
```

`

Here is the output :[image],

Also I have a separate dart file for a custom drawer I want to be displayed when the hamburger menu icon is tapped. How can I make that possible?

Here is the code for custom drawer:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DrawerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DrawerScreenState createState() => _DrawerScreenState();
}

class _DrawerScreenState extends State<DrawerScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 28,
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 50,
                backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/joker.jpg'),
              ),
            ),
            title: Text(
              'Joaquin Phoenix',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 14,
              ),
            ),
            subtitle: Text(
              "You wouldn't get it",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  fontSize: 10.0),
            ),
          )
        ],
      )),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue[50],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can copy paste run two full code below 
Step 1: `_DrawerScreenState` remove `Scaffold` 
Step 2: For `drawer` background color, you can wrap with `Theme`

```
class _DrawerScreenState extends State<DrawerScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        canvasColor: Colors.blue[50],
      ),
      child: Drawer(
```

Step 3: Use `DrawerScreen()` in `main.dart`

```
SafeArea(
    child: Scaffold(
        drawer: DrawerScreen(),
```

Step 4: wrap `Icons.menu` with `Builder` and open with `openDrawer()`

```
Builder(
        builder: (context) => GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.menu)),
      ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code `main.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hexcolor/hexcolor.dart';
import 'drawer.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            drawer: DrawerScreen(),
            appBar: PreferredSize(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, top: 10, bottom: 10),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Builder(
                        builder: (context) => GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
                            },
                            child: Icon(Icons.menu)),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Appbar',
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Icon(Icons.search)
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(40)),
            backgroundColor: Hexcolor('#e9f1fe'),
            body: Center(
              child: Text('Experimenting drawer'),
            )));
  }
}
```

full code `drawer.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DrawerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DrawerScreenState createState() => _DrawerScreenState();
}

class _DrawerScreenState extends State<DrawerScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        canvasColor: Colors.blue[50],
      ),
      child: Drawer(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 28,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 50,
                    backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/joker.jpg'),
                  ),
                ),
                title: Text(
                  'Joaquin Phoenix',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 14,
                  ),
                ),
                subtitle: Text(
                  "You wouldn't get it",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      fontSize: 10.0),
                ),
              )
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```